# LWC - How to send the recordId to the controller

Tags: lightning-web-components, api

I'm trying to pass the recordId to the controller so I can interact with the person account to send the data. The problem I found was that recordId was not sending its data correctly to the controller. So I did console.log recordId and it was giving me an undefined. Any idea of getting recordId?

.js

```js
      @api recordId;

      async connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.recordId) // this will give me undefined
        uploadImage({
          fileName: 'image.png',
          base64Data: image_data_url,
          recordId: this.recordId,
        })
      }

     photoShot() {
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // draw html5 canvas
        const image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
     }
```

.cls

```java
        @AuraEnabled
        public static string uploadImage(String fileName, String base64Data, Id recordId) {
            // Decoding the base64Data
            base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
            cv.Title = fileName;
            cv.PathOnClient = '/' + fileName;
            cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
            cv.FirstPublishLocationId = recordId;
            Insert cv;

            ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
            cdl.ContentDocumentId = [
                  SELECT ContentDocumentId 
                  FROM ContentVersion 
                  WHERE Id =: cv.Id
                ].ContentDocumentId;
            cdl.LinkedEntityId = recordId;
            cdl.ShareType = 'V';
            cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
            insert cdl;
            System.debug('ContentDocumentLink');
            System.debug(cdl.Id);
        }
```

.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle 
    xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <targets>
            <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
            <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
            <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
            <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
            <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        </targets>
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
                <property
                    name="recordId"
                    type="String"
                    label="Record Id"
                    description="Automatically bind the page's record id to the component variable"
                    default="{!recordId}" />
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: As suggested in the answer, check the context of use. Is this in a lightning record page or appropriate digital experience page that has a mapping for the recordId in its URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the record id you need to add the component to a Lightning record page.
You need to also import the `@api` like below:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
```

Please note that

> "The recordId is set only when you place or invoke the component in an
> explicit record context. In all other cases, the recordId isn’t set,
> and your component can’t depend on it."

If your component is added on an Expereince Site then you need to add the following in your meta file:

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property
            name="recordId"
            type="String"
            label="Record Id"
            description="Automatically bind the page's record id to the component variable"
            default="{!recordId}" />
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

For your reference please refer to the following [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context)

Comment: There is always the case where the recordId is explicitly set by a parent component on this child component...

Comment: @Krishnan Mishra Hey thanks for the help. I put a new code there for the xml file. Take a look there, It is still giving me undefined on console.log(this.recordId).

Comment: @IanLee Can you please specify where are you using this component?

Comment: Okay, I'm getting base64 data from a camera and trying to send that data to person account(file). but in order to do that I need to use controller with pass in parameter(recordId, base64, fileName). I can pass in base64 and fileName but the recordId. I have set the xml just now but still not getting the initial value from console.log(this.recordId) which makes me to assume that It's still not getting the recordId.

Comment: @IanLee Your custom lwc component must be rendered on a Lightning record page then only you can use the native recordId. What I was asking you was where(like Record Detail page, community) is your lwc component being rendered?

Comment: @Krishnan Mishra I'm trying to figure that out right now sorry for the delay

Comment: @Krishnana Mishra Hey currently I'm just testing things out in the "How to Launch" lightning url.

Comment: @IanLee Please check the answer posted. I've also attached a link for your reference for the same as well.

Comment: @Krishnana Mishra Yes it is the record page